# $7$ friends promise to each send a postcard to $3$ others. Is it possible that everybody receives postcards only from people they sent postcards to?

Tags: graph-theory

This is a task meant to be solved using graph theory. My intuition says that it is not possible, however I don't know how to prove it apart from just drawing graphs with seven nodes in various configurations of connections between those nodes. I will appreciate any help or nudge in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: How many postcards will have been sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine if you will a directed graph detailing the scenario.  A vertex for each of the friends.  Draw a directed arrow from one friend to another iff the first friend sent a postcard to the other friend.

Now... the condition "*everybody receives postcards only from people they sent postcards to*" would imply that in every case where you have a directed edge from one friend to another you would also necessarily have a directed edge in the other direction and there would be no other such edges.

So... let us imagine now a graph rather than a directed graph, just like before, except this time we only draw the one undirected edge between friends indicating that both had mailed each other.

Such a graph would have $7$ vertices and each vertex would be of degree $3$.

Why is this not possible?

> Because the handshaking lemma implies that we may not have an odd number of odd-degree vertices.